# Codepen Preview not Applying All CSS

Tags: html, css, codepen

I am having trouble getting a preview of one of my codepens to display properly on a web page. Essentially, I am writing an article in a text editor that supports markdown. All I have to do to post a codepen is paste the link. However, when I do, the preview looks wrong. Here are two pictures illustrating the issue (the first is wrong, while the second is correct):
[image]

[image]

As you can see, the preview version doesn't seem to be applying my `transform` and margin styles properly. Here is my code:

```css
/* General/reset styles */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: #333;
}

.new-section {
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: 100;
}

/* Header styles */

header {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #69bcf4, #30cc8b);
  color: #fff;
}

header h1 {
  padding-top: calc(50vh - 113px);
  font-size: 7em;
  font-weight: 100;
}

header h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
}

header span.animated {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 50px;
  height: 4px;
  width: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

header span::before,
header span::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -23px;
  content: "";
  height: 30px;
  width: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #fff;
}

header span::before {
  left: -10px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

header span::after {
  right: -10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

/* Media queries */

@media (max-width: 759px) {
  header h1 {
    font-size: 5em;
  }
  
  .new-section {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
  
  .scroll-animations {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .scroll-animations div {
    padding: 20px 80px;
  }
  
  .click-animations input,
  .click-animations textarea,
  .click-animations button {
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 475px) {
  .new-section {
    font-size: 2.5em;
  } 
  
  header h1 {
    font-size: 3.2em;
  }
  
  header h2,
  .funky-animations h3 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
  <h1 class="animated bounceInDown">Animate.css</h1>
  <h2 class="animated bounceInDown">Level Up Your Websites with Animate.css</h2>
  <span class="animated bounce"></span>
</header>
```

If it helps, you can look at the actual pen [here](https://codepen.io/Hudson_Taylor11/pen/xqeQva). Any thoughts or things I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried any developer tools or debuggers?

Comment: What exactly is missing? It seems to be working fine for me: http://imgur.com/8hseJ64

Comment: Hmmm... Personally, I'd just add `<br />`s after the `<h1>`, but that's probably not correct...

Comment: Link to the codepen? Or any particular browser you're using? The sample code snippet works fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: It does for me too. But, the preview is messed up as the first pic shows... Do you see how the arrow is wrong?

Comment: Without a link to your actual codepen I'm not sure anyone will able to help you. We can't replicate it.

Comment: I'll add the link.

Comment: Link works fine for me. Tell us exactly what browser, version, etc you are using. Can't help if can't reproduce.

Comment: Ok, will edit accordingly.

Comment: It's working on my end.

Comment: Your snippet code also work too.

Comment: Where do you get that preview - it looks ok when I search your public projects ? Re the arrow, that is constructed from CSS before & after clauses, so maybe the rendering engine for the preview is not compliant to that level of css?

Comment: It works for me. Anyway, sites like Codepen or jsFiddle (I strongly prefer last) cannot properly handle **all** circumstances. When you play with elements like `*`, `html`, `body` - it has a big chance that you will need just local copy of your html/css/js files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recreated the codepen embed here using the settings you used: https://codepen.io/ksmessy/pen/EmrBdV

On the Embed pen button, when using the "Use click to load" default state check box (see below)

[image: click-to-load]

...it just generates a screenshot of your pen and hosts it on Codepen's Amazon Web Services account (example: http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/i.cdpn.io/603854.xqeQva.ff9bf8bc-b13e-4285-9dd9-218ff376997c.png), and puts that image as a background placeholder until the "Run Pen" button is clicked.

So it looks like whatever service is taking the screenshot, doesn't support `transform: rotate(45deg);` - it needs to be prefixed.

I made a new pen here, with prefixes added in:

https://codepen.io/ksmessy/pen/oWmKwp (I just did it the easy way - pen Settings, CSS, Vendor Prefixing, check the "Autoprefixer" checkbox)

I embedded it here, and the arrow looks normal:

https://codepen.io/ksmessy/pen/bWzXry

In summary: add a prefix to transform: rotate.

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
transform: rotate(-45deg);
```

After you update yours, I'm not sure how often the screenshot of a pen is updated, but once it does and the cache clears then the arrow should look correct.

Comment: This looks great! Thanks. I'll mark it as correct once mine updates.

Comment: If it still hasn't updated the screenshot, copying all the code over to a new Pen and embedding that one should ensure a new screenshot happens sooner.